# Patent Word Limit

Tags: fees, word-limit

I'd like to know whether there is a word limit for the patent description (summary and detailed summary)?

If not, is there an overall paper/word limit before fees accrue? That is, after how many patent pages will you be charged for going over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from the USPTO's current fee schedule:

> 1.16(s)
>   Utility Application Size Fee - for each additional 50 sheets that exceeds 100 sheets
>
> Large entity $400.00;    Small entity $200.00;   Micro entry $100.00

Every piece of paper (or virtual page) is counted including the claims and abstract and drawings.  If you give them a program listing or DNA sequence a CD those pages don't count.